# cscope failed at "cs add"printing "cs_read_prompt EOF: Interrupted system call"

Tags: vim, cscope

### Environment:

1. Linux Mint 14 MATE **amd64** Desktop (Ubuntu 12.10 like)
2. cscope **15.7a**-3.6 (Ubuntu source)
3. vim **7.3** (Ubuntu source)
4. mate-terminal

### Description:

When I command "vim xx.c" in mate-terminal, vim invokes cscope executing "cs add $PROJ/cscope.out" but failed with message:

```
Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/cscope_maps.vim:
line   46:
cs_read_prompt EOF: Interrupted system call
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

**cscope_maps.vim** line 46 here:

```
if filereadable("cscope.out")
   cs add cscope.out

elseif $CSCOPE_DB != ""
    cs add $CSCOPE_DB   //line 46 here
endif
```

I have exported $CSCOPE_DB correctly coz it sometimes worked. Still It happens randomly.
I use *"cscope -Rbkg"* working under *$PROJ dir*. The problem happens when I work in *$PROJ/subdir*. Sometimes I can open file with vim normaly without error message. I have tried using cscope-15.6 compiled from source tarball. This never comes out on my CentOS 6.3. 
Has any buddy have any suggestions?

Comment: Is `$PROJ` defined? Is there a `$PROJ/cscope.out` file?

Comment: yep, $PROJ is just a substitution. The problem happened frequently when opening *multiple* virtual terminals.